# the limit of $x_{n}$ where $x_{n+1}=(-1)^{n}\arctan(x_{n})$ and $x_{0}=1$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Let $x_{0}=1$ and $x_{n+1}=(-1)^{n}(\frac{\pi }{2}-\arctan(\frac{1}{x_{n}}))$
>
> I have the following options to choose from:
>
> 1. $x_n$ is unbounded
> 2. $x_n$ is increasing and the limit of  $x_n$ is $1$
> 3. the limit of $x_n$ is $\pi/2$.
> 4. the limit of $x_n$ is $0$

**My attempt:**

I used $$\arctan(x)+\arctan(\frac{1}{x})=\frac{\pi }{2}$$ so 
$$
x_{n+1} = (-1)^n \arctan(x_n)
        = \begin{cases}
 \arctan(x_n) & \text{ if } n=2k \\ 
-\arctan(x_n) & \text{ if } n=2k+1 
\end{cases}
$$

I think I should take $y_{0}=1$ and $y_{n+1}=\arctan(y_{n})$

$y_{0}=1;y_{1}=pi/4$ so the sequence is decreasing.How to find the last term? I mean how long it decreasing ?It should be 
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \arctan(y_{n})=\frac{\pi }{2},
$$
right?

How to approach this exercise?There is another way to find the monotony of the sequence?How to find the lower limit of the sequence?

Comment: As the sign of $x_n$ alternates, it will not be monotone. However, what can you say about the monotony of $|x_n|$ ?

Comment: Also, note that $y_0 > y_1$ doesn't imply that the full sequence is decreasing.

Comment: It decreasing because $-$ disappear so $x_{n}$ becomes $y_{n}$ from my question, right?

Comment: Note that when $x \neq 0$, $\arctan{x}+\arctan{\frac{1}{x}}=sign(x)\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: If I would show that $y_{n}$ from my question is decreasing and it's bounded then it's convergent.Then, if I note the limit of  $y_{n}$ with $L$ I would get $L=arctan(L)$ so $L=0$ so the initial sequence has the limit $0$ too.

Comment: You can consider $f(x)=-\arctan(\arctan(x)$ and $x_{n+2}=f(x_n)$. It is clear that $f'(x)=-\frac 1{(1+x^2)(1+\arctan(x)^2)}$ is negative so $f\ \searrow$ and also $|f'|<1$. So you get adjacent sequences for $x_{2n+1}$ and $x_{2n}$ both converging monotonously to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

The title does not match the question in the box. As pointed out by other users, $\arctan(1/x)$ need not equal $\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan x$ if $x < 0$, and in fact,

$\hspace{7em}$ [image: Comparison]

Indeed, the following plot, which demonstrates the first 50 terms of $(x_n)$, clearly indicates that none of the options is true for the sequence $(x_n)$ defined as in the box (as opposed to what is appearing in the title).

[image: First 50 terms]

Answer (score 0):

Since $-\pi/2\lt\arctan x\lt\pi/2$ for all $x$, we have $0\lt\pi/2-\arctan(1/x_n)\lt\pi$ if $x_n\not=0$, hence $0\lt|x_{n+1}|\lt\pi$ for all $n$, which eliminates option 1. This also shows that the sequence alternates in sign, so it cannot have a nonzero limit, which eliminates options 2 and 3. We are left with option 4 as the only possible answer. If this is a question on a multiple-choice test, that's all you need to know.